# Laravel 5.3 Query Not Return Result

Tags: laravel

I am a writing a query in laravel 5.3 but query not return any data

when i run query in direct in mysql then it's work

query here

```
return DB::table('friends')
            ->join('users', function ($join) use ($user_id){
                $join->on(function ($joinin) use ($user_id){
                    $joinin->where('friends.user_one_id', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->where('friends.user_one_id', '!=',$user_id);
                })->orwhere(function ($andwhere) use ($user_id){
                    $andwhere->where('friends.user_two_id', '=' ,'users.id')
                     ->where('friends.user_two_id', '!=' ,$user_id);
                });
            })->where('status','=','1')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($user_id){
                $query->where('user_one_id', '=', $user_id)
                    ->orwhere('user_two_id', '=', $user_id);
            })->get();
```

and it possible that make this query using Eloquent ORM

Comment: Is the query builder smart enough to change != to <>

Comment: Yes. Eloquent is smart enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `get()`, try appending `toSql()` instead and inspect the result. This will show you the query that the query builder has built so you can compare it to the raw query you've written, and see if you can narrow down where you went wrong.

Also, that query would work fine in Eloquent, just use `Friend::join...` instead of `DB::table('friends')`.